# How to split dictionary into multiple dictionaries fast

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have found a solution but it is really slow:

```
def chunks(self,data, SIZE=10000):
    for i in xrange(0, len(data), SIZE):
        yield dict(data.items()[i:i+SIZE])
```

Do you have any ideas without using external modules (numpy and etc.)

Comment: Don't keep calling `items`. You're making a new list of all the items every time you just want a slice.

Comment: yeah i know that, but the problem is that i can't find a different method to split my dictionary into equal sized chunks.

Comment: Try the [`grouper` recipe from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Comment: @badc0re: still, don't keep calling `items`. do it once.

Comment: note: I don't see how splitting a dictionary can be useful... what the heck are you doing?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Since the dictionary is so big, it would be better to keep all the items involved to be just iterators and generators, like this

```
from itertools import islice

def chunks(data, SIZE=10000):
    it = iter(data)
    for i in range(0, len(data), SIZE):
        yield {k:data[k] for k in islice(it, SIZE)}
```

**Sample run:**

```
for item in chunks({i:i for i in xrange(10)}, 3):
    print(item)
```

**Output**

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
{3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5}
{8: 8, 6: 6, 7: 7}
{9: 9}
```

Comment: Great answer. Use `range()` instead of `xrange()` in Python3

Comment: Could you elaborate on how/why iterators/generators more preferable - is it for memory efficiency?

Comment: If you use Python 3.12 or newer, you can use `itertools.batched` instead of `itertools.islice`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77832086/10266970) for details.

Answer (score 7):

For Python 3+.

[`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) was renamed to [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) in Python 3+.

You can use;

```
from itertools import islice

def chunks(data, SIZE=10000):
   it = iter(data)
   for i in range(0, len(data), SIZE):
      yield {k:data[k] for k in islice(it, SIZE)}
```

Sample:

```
for item in chunks({i:i for i in range(10)}, 3):
   print(item)
```

With following output.

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
{3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5}
{6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8}
{9: 9}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another method is iterators zipping:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest, ifilter
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6, 'g':7, 'h':8}
```

Create a list with copies of dict iterators (number of copies is number of elements in result dicts). By passing each iterator from `chunks` list to [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) you will get needed number of elements from source dict ([`ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) used to remove `None` from zip results). With generator expression you can lower memory usage:

```
>>> chunks = [d.iteritems()]*3
>>> g = (dict(ifilter(None, v)) for v in izip_longest(*chunks))
>>> list(g)
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2},
 {'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'g': 7},
 {'h': 8, 'f': 6}]
```

Comment: If taking this approach in Python 3, it's important to replace `d.iteritems()` with `iter(d.items())`, and not just `d.items()`. This is because @npdu's approach relies on the fact that you're exhausting the same iterator (so the view object returned by `d.items()` in Python 3 doesn't fulfill the same role). Other changes that you would make are replacing `izip_longest` with `zip_longest` and `ifilter` with the built-in `filter`.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.12 introduces [batched](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched) function in `itertools` module. It allows to batch the data from iterable to tuples of `size` passed as second parameter. Using it, you can simplify implementation from the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22878842/10266970):

```py
from itertools import batched

def chunks(data, SIZE=10000):
    for batch in batched(data.items(), SIZE):
        yield dict(batch)
```

or even make it a one-liner:

```py
from itertools import batched

def chunks(data, SIZE=10000):
    return (dict(batch) for batch in batched(data.items(), SIZE))
```

When tested performance of iterating over this generator for dict with million entries and batches of size 10000, it took about 0.2 seconds on my hardware, which is 33% less than 0.3 seconds per run of solution from the top answer.

Also, [Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy) proposed even simpler solution in comments with pretty much identical performance:

```py
from itertools import batched

def chunks(data, SIZE=10000):
    return map(dict, batched(data.items(), SIZE))
```

Performance improvement comes from using `dict()` and iterating over items, instead of creating the dict in the comprehension, so if you can't use Python >= 3.12, you can go with:

```py
from itertools import islice

def chunks(data, SIZE=10000):
    it = iter(data.items())
    for i in range(0, len(data), SIZE):
        yield dict(islice(it, SIZE))
```

Comment: Your `yield from` is purely wasteful, no point wrapping your generator iterator in another generator iterator which does nothing but slow it down. How about `return map(dict, batched(data.items(), SIZE))` (not tested, don't have 3.12)?

Comment: Makes sense, I could just return a generator from comprehension. This `yield from` doesn't impact the performance in any noticeable way though.

`map` based solution proposed by you also works like a charm with pretty much identical performance to those from my answer.

Comment: Yeah, with SIZE=10000, almost all time is spent by the underlying operations (batching and dict-building). You *might* see a little difference with *small* SIZE values. But mostly I meant this out of principle. A generator that does nothing but `yield from genexp` is just strictly worse than `return genexp` and in other cases it can make a noticeable difference.

Comment: Agreed, I replaced `yield from` with `return` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code takes a large dictionary and splits it into a list of small dictionaries. max_limit variable is to tell maximum number of key-value pairs allowed in a sub-dictionary. 
This code doesn't take much effort to break the dictionary, just one complete parsing over the dictionary object.

```
import copy
def split_dict_to_multiple(input_dict, max_limit=200):
"""Splits dict into multiple dicts with given maximum size. 
Returns a list of dictionaries."""
chunks = []
curr_dict ={}
for k, v in input_dict.items():
    if len(curr_dict.keys()) < max_limit:
        curr_dict.update({k: v})
    else:
        chunks.append(copy.deepcopy(curr_dict))
        curr_dict = {k: v}
# update last curr_dict
chunks.append(curr_dict)
return chunks
```

Comment: better to provide some explanation with code snippets

Answer (score 1):

This code works in Python 3.8 and does not use any external modules:

```
def split_dict(d, n):
    keys = list(d.keys())
    for i in range(0, len(keys), n):
        yield {k: d[k] for k in keys[i: i + n]}


for item in split_dict({i: i for i in range(10)}, 3):
    print(item)
```

prints this:

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
{3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5}
{6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8}
{9: 9}
```

... and might even be slightly faster than the (currently) [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22878842/11538412) of thefourtheye:

```
from hwcounter import count, count_end


start = count()
for item in chunks({i: i for i in range(100000)}, 3):
    pass
elapsed = count_end() - start
print(f'elapsed cycles: {elapsed}')

start = count()
for item in split_dict({i: i for i in range(100000)}, 3):
    pass
elapsed = count_end() - start
print(f'elapsed cycles: {elapsed}')
```

prints

```
elapsed cycles: 145773597
elapsed cycles: 138041191
```

Comment: Why do not you use the Python's 'timeit' module to measure performance?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work, with only builtins:

```
>>> adict = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}
>>> chunklen = 2
>>> dictlist = list(adict.items())
>>> [ dict(dictlist[i:i + chunklen]) for i in range(0, len(dictlist), chunklen) ]
[{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}, {3: 'c', 4: 'd'}]
```

This preps the original dictionary into a list of items, but you could possibly could do that in a one-liner.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
chunk_size = 3
chunked_data = [[k, v] for k, v in d.items()]
chunked_data = np.array_split(chunked_data, chunk_size)
```

Afterwards you have `ndarray` which is iterable like this:

```
for chunk in chunked_data:
    for key, value in chunk:
        print(key)
        print(value)
```

Which could be re-assigned to a list of dicts using a simple for loop.

Comment: Perhaps downvoted because it's an obvious overkill to use a numpy ndarray to chunk native dictionaries. The OP expressed the need to not use any external module, explicitly mentioning numpy.