# Python: split a dict in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to convert a simple dict like so: `d = {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3}` to a list of dict with the same amount of elements in each of them (or so) as this one: `[{0:0, 2:2}, {1:1, 3:3}]`. I've tried with simple indexing like I use with lists but it throws me a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`. Here what i have right now:

```
def dico_chunks(dico, n):
    if len(dico) < n:
        n = len(dico)
    return [dico[i::n] for i in range(n)]
```

Keep in mind that i don't need the list to be order in anyway. I just need to have my main dict splited in a list of `n` sub-dicts.

Comment: You need to decide on a rule for which elements to put in the same dictionary inside the list.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered collections, the items don't have a natural index number associated with them. You could split the dict's keys list, but bear in mind that that list may not be in the order that you expect.

Comment: Can you make the rule for splitting more clearly?

Comment: I need each value in the main dict to appear only once in any sub-dict. I just need to split my main dict in a number of smaller dict (`n`) with the same number of value in each sub-dict.

Comment: Does the accepted answer in the linked question do what you want?

Comment: No it doesn't since the last arg is not the number of chunks/dicts to return but the size of the chunks. @PM2Ring

Comment: Well, that's only a minor issue, and schwobaseggl has shown how to perform the necessary calculation. Of course, if the chunk size isn't a divisor of the list length then some chunks will be smaller than the specified size. I was more concerned that the code in the accepted answer of the linked question splits the original dict into contiguous blocks, rather than doing what your `dico[i::n] for i in range(n)` attempts to do.

Comment: Yup just accepted the answer! Had a hard time figuring out schwobaseggl  codes but everthings fine! I'm sorry I've waste your time, gentlemen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generator based approach:

```
def chunk_dict(d, chunk_size):
    r = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if len(r) == chunk_size:
            yield r
            r = {}
        r[k] = v
    if r:
        yield r

d = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6}
list(chunk_dict(d, 2))
# [{1: 1, 2: 2}, {3: 3, 4: 4}, {5: 5, 6: 6}]
```

A shorter and more performant version of the same functionality (using `itertools.islice`)
can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878743/how-to-split-dictionary-into-multiple-dictionaries-fast#answer-22878842).

For a given number of as evenly as possible distributed chunks (e.g. sizes 4, 4, 3, 3 instead of 4, 4, 4, 2), you can do:

```
chunks = [{} for _ in range(num_chunks)]
for i, k in enumerate(d):
    chunks[i % num_chunks][k] = d[v]
```

Comment: Instead of the `chunk_size` arg, I receive the `number_of_chunks` wich determine the chunk size itself.

Comment: `chunk_size = len(d) // num_chunks` or similar will get you from one to the other.

Comment: FWIW, I was going to post something like: `items = sorted(dico.items())` `n = min(n, len(dico))` `return [dict(items[i::n]) for i in range(n)]`...

Comment: @Marc-AntoineGiguère You might like to play around with the code I just put in my previous comment.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yup, that's the cleverer (maybe more cryptic) version :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `pairwise` function defined in [Iterate through pairs of items in a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764782/iterate-through-pairs-of-items-in-a-python-list), passing it the `items()` of the dict:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

d = {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3}

list(map(dict,pairwise(d.items())))
# [{0: 0, 1: 1}, {1: 1, 2: 2}, {2: 2, 3: 3}]
```

If you want non-repeating pairs, then you can use `zip`:

```
items = list(d.items())

list(map(dict, zip(items[::2], items[1::2])))
# [{0: 0, 1: 1}, {2: 2, 3: 3}]
```

Dictionaries are fundamentally unordered, so if you want a particular order you need to specify that using some other logic.