# Splitting a array in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

How do you split an array in python in terms of the number of elements in the array. Im doing knn classification and I need to take into account of the first k elements of the 2D array.

Comment: Did you ask Python to split it ? Try being polite this time!? :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split list into smaller lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752308/split-list-into-smaller-lists)

Comment: Are you talking about a normal python list (which is called an array in other languages) or a numpy array ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 7])

print(x[range(0, 4)])
```

You can also split it up by taking the range of elements that you want to work with. You could store x[range(x, x)]) in a variable and work with those particular elements of the array as well. The output as you can see splits the array up:

```
[1 2 4 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Numpy, there is a method [numpy.split.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)

```
x = np.arange(9.0)
np.split(x, 3)
```