# numbered List transfer to bins

Tags: python, list

If I have a list:

```
a=[6,3,2,5,1,4]
```

and a specific size likes 3, 
so number 1~2 will tagged 1, 3~4 tagged 2, 5~6 tagged 3, likes list b:

```
b=[3,2,1,3,1,2]
```

How can I efficient to do this?
Note that list could be floating number

Sorry for unclear description,
Update with more complex example:

```
a=[2.5,1.4,1.6,2.1,1.5,0.7]
```

output will be :

```
b=[3,1,2,3,2,1]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split list into smaller lists (split in half)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752308/split-list-into-smaller-lists-split-in-half)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need :

```
import math
a=[6,3,2,5,1,4]
size = 3
b = list(a)
b.sort()
for i in range(len(a)) :
    w = len(b)/size                             #1
    a[i] = math.ceil((b.index(a[i]) + 1)/(w))   #2

print(a)
```

1:  we're getting the length of each chunk

2:  we're getting in which chunk the number is present in our sorted list and replacing it with the number of the chunk in the original list

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by first ordering the list, and [splitting it into chunks of the desired size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752308/split-list-into-smaller-lists):

```
a=[6,3,2,5,1,4]
n = 3

a_ord = sorted(a)

def split_list(alist, wanted_parts=1):
    length = len(alist)
    return [ alist[i*length // wanted_parts: (i+1)*length // wanted_parts] 
             for i in range(wanted_parts) ]

x = split_list(a_ord,n)
```

And then crating a dictionary using these chunks as the bins:

```
d = {j:x.index(i)+1 for i in x for j in i}

print(d)
>>> {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 3}
```

And then mapping the values using the dictionary:

```
b = [d[key] for key in a]

print(b)
>>> [3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sample_dict = {
        1:1,
        2:1,
        3:2,
        4:2,
        5:3,
        6:3
    }

for k in a:
    out_arr.append(sample_dict[k])
    
print (out_arr)
```

Comment: This is a hard-coded dictionary and will not work with a different size of array or bin size.