# Split array Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of size `(1, 100, 81)`.

I want to remove the first column of the array and I need an array of size `(1, 99, 81)`.

How to split the array into `(1, 1, 81)` and `(1, 99, 81)`. I tried using `np.split()` but I think I am wrong for this type of array.

**Reminder:** I don't want to split into halves.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split list into smaller lists (split in half)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752308/split-list-into-smaller-lists-split-in-half)

Comment: Not splitting the array into half. Btw I got the answer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Your welcome, the article was specifically about splitting in half but you can use the implementation for your purposes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one if you use numpy array

```
 array = array[0, 1:,:]
```

Comment: @Krush23 If it works should select it as the answer

Comment: I cant select the answer below 10 mins :-)

Comment: Oh yeah right forgot about it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
list2 = [list1[0].pop(0)]
```

should do it, assuming `list1` is a standard python list-of-lists-of-lists. This removes the first "column" of `list1` using `pop(0)`, and then puts it into a new list, all in one step.