# How to Split a mongoDB Collection that has been exported to a .json file?

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have a .json file which contains some data and was obtained by exporting a mongoDB database collection. In order to test perform Machine Learning Training and Testing on the data, I want to split the json file into 2 separate files following a particular test-train ratio, which I'm unable to do on my Python notebook, or on the mongoDB console.

I have tried to manually split the records using notepad, but that doesn't ensure accuracy I need for splitting.

I also tried converting the json file to a Pandas dataframe, but then I lose the format in which data is stored, since `to_json()` saves all the records of the first column first, second column second, and so on, which I don't want.

My json file is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OzLM9oG1gS5RVC1PGF3oejvd-I5W1syB/view?usp=sharing)!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your file is, that it's not a valid json. If you had a valid json you could just use json.loads() to have your entries as a python list and split that list e.g. like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/752330/7592395). For your file, one way would be to convert to valid json. But if you want to keep the current form you could just do a file split for the relevant lines. So this should work:

```
import math

fname_all = 'reddit_india_using_mongoexport.json'
fname_train = 'reddit_india_using_mongoexport_train.json'
fname_test = 'reddit_india_using_mongoexport_test.json'

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

len = file_len(fname_all)

split_ratio = 0.8

f_train = open(fname_train, "w+")
f_test = open(fname_test, "w+")

with open(fname_all) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            if i < math.floor(len*split_ratio):
                f_train.write(l)
            else:
                f_test.write(l)

f_train.close()
f_test.close()

print('Original file:' + str(file_len(fname_all)))
print('Train file:' + str(file_len(fname_train)))
print('Test file:' + str(file_len(fname_test)))
```

It gives you:

> Original file:8076
>
> Train file:6460
>
> Test file:1616

Comment: Why is it not a valid json? And how do you convert to a valid json

Comment: I'm getting the following error: 
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 1436: character maps to <undefined> `