# Splitting tabular data in python

Tags: python, split, tabular

I've coded a program that gives me data in tabular form (using tabulate) in python:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

matrix=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]

print(tabulate(matrix))
```

It gives me this output:

[image]

Now say that I want to split this table in 2 such that it gives:

[image]

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752308/split-list-into-smaller-lists-split-in-half) to split a normal array into two arrays. In the for loop, we split every one of the arrays in the matrix with the function. When you want to get the first part change the 1 to a 0.

```
from tabulate import tabulate

def split_list(a_list):
    half = len(a_list)//2
    return a_list[:half], a_list[half:]

matrix=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
new_matrix = []

for arr in matrix:
    new_matrix.append(split_list(arr)[1]) #Replace this 1 with a 0

print(tabulate(new_matrix))
```

or just

```
from tabulate import tabulate

def split_list(a_list):
    half = len(a_list)//2
    return a_list[:half], a_list[half:]

matrix=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
new_matrix = split_list(matrix[1])


print(tabulate(new_matrix))
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, however I have to split the table directly not the list.

Comment: why? you can save it in a variable and access it.

Comment: You can also do it like this new_matrix = split_list(matrix[1]) without the for loop. Does this help?

Comment: because it needs to be able to take in any tabular data, even the ones that aren't created using lists

Comment: I am sorry I dont understand it could you give an example? Couldnt you convert the data to lists? The matrix is just a list in a list

Comment: Yes, if I can convert the table to a list after the table is created I can use that, I can't modify the list before it is created into a table form however

Comment: When you use those matrixes as tables then they are already lists